# How to make Leaflet maps accessible and WCAG2 compliant

Tags: leaflet, accessibility

I have followed several threads on this topic but have not been able to 
fix the following issues:

1. How to prevent Leaflet map tile images names from being read out by screen readers?
2. How to make vector layers (like Circles and Rectangles) tabbable?
3. How to make tile images not selectable - is this related to #1?

I have tried with current Leaflet distribution 0.7.5 and 1.0 Beta2 - without any success.  Here are some  related discussions:

[Leaflet issue: accessibility improvements](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3210)

[StackOverflow: how to make Leaflet tile layers accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745454/how-to-make-leaflet-tile-layers-accessible)

Does anyone have a link to share - to a Leaflet based site/page that is WCAG2 compliant?

Comment: I think you're probably going to have more luck with this question on StackOverflow, since that site (and your question) is more code oriented

Answer (score 1):

Regarding item #1: [this commit](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/commit/c1870976e6e3f1b32fffcd8f28c8ae4952ff7dea) should have taken care of that for 1.0-beta1. If it doesn't, please do file a detailed bug report in Leaflet's github issue tracker.

Item #2: If you know a way to make SVG paths tabbable, please do share. We the Leaflet devs are not aware of whether that can be done at all. In case the map uses a `<canvas>` renderer, I see no real way of achieving "tabbability", short of implementing it manually.

Item #3: Leaflet disables selection and image dragging during map drag operations, see [this code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/dom/Draggable.js#L58). How are you able to select an image?